# Can MySQL group results into specific intervals?

Tags: mysql

A DB holds records of `Projects` and each of these projects stores the number of hours that have been worked on this project.

I would like to create some simple statistics which show how many projects with X hours exists:

```
Projecs
id  |  name  |  hours |  ...
----+--------+--------+--------
 1  |  P1    |    5   |   ...   
----+--------+--------+--------
 2  |  P2    |   20   |   ...    
----+--------+--------+--------
 3  |  P3    |    9   |   ...  
----+--------+--------+--------
 4  |  P4    |   28   |   ...   
----+--------+--------+--------
 5  |  P5    |   42   |   ...    
----+--------+--------+--------
 6  |  P6    |    8   |   ...

 0-10 hours ==> 3
11-20 hours ==> 0
21-30 hours ==> 1
31-40 hours ==> 0
41-50 hours ==> 1
```

Of course this can easily be done with a simple `SELECT` statement that returns all rows and a `for` loops that runs through all results and split them up into the desired intervals/groups.

**Question is: Can this be done in MySQL alone?**

Comment: Add a column with case statement checking condition alike mentioned above.. say case when hours between 0 and 10 then 1 . Similarly 2,3,4,5 for 11-20,21-30,31-40,41-50. Then group by using that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group by a gap of 10 hours, you can use...

```
SELECT count(id) from Projects group by truncate(hours/10,0)
```

Change the 10 to be the interval you need.